# Bad Request error using SendGrid SMTP email submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I am currently using C# in MVC4 ASP.NET 4.5.

My application creates a user and then submits a registration email to that use to authenticate their email. To create this script, I followed this tutorial: [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/)

I am using the latest version of [SendGrid (2.1.1)](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/)

Code specific namespaces being used:

```
using SendGridMail;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Here is my code that creates the SendGrid mail message:

```
SendGrid message = SendGrid.GetInstance();
message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail); //fromEmail is a MailAddress type
message.AddTo(userName); //this is a string
message.Html = body; //this is also a string
```

Then I go to send the email:

```
//Create login info for email
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var trasnportSMTP = Web.GetInstance(credentials);
trasnportSMTP.Deliver(message); //smtp.sendgrid.net Send message
```

On the last line where "trasnportSMTP.Deliver(message);" I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> **Bad Request**
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Exception: Bad Request

**The only things I've noticed while tracing is in the Exception Snapshot in View Details and the Output window.**

I noticed that the: 
TargetSite = {Void CheckForErrors(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)}, 
ReturnType is {Name = "Void" FullName = "System.Void"}, 
ReflectedType is {Name = "Web" FullName = "SendGridMail.Web"}, 
CustomAttributes - Count = 0, 
Name = "CheckForErrors", 
It's in the Module {SendGridMail.dll}.

Also in my output, there is the following:

> "A first chance exception of type `'System.FormatException'` occurred
>   in System.dll Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   `'SendGridMail.Web.Deliver'`"

Can anyone give me some more insight on why this error is happening. I am using the correct username and password that is on the SendGrid account on Azure.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: not to be a smart ass, but try drilling into the stack trace.

Comment: See edits at the bottom of what I found while tracing and in the output window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the subject to your message

```
message.Subject = "this is the subject";
```

That should do it, I ran into the same problem when I was playing with this library.

Comment: Wow...I can't believe that is what I forgot. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, that's an awesomely obfuscated error for a missing subject.

Comment: Same thing for a null or empty Text.

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me (I'm using Azure):

[SendGrid Tutorial resulting in Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113455/sendgrid-tutorial-resulting-in-bad-request)

In short: you need to get your credentials through azure (connect info at the marketplace), you might be using the wrong ones.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the documentation if you need to use the key which looks like something closer to "SG.asasfhiouce-JKIjjkvcdb_iouywerejkhwrnd" you should use the exact word "apikey" as the username and that key as the password

If it didn't work, try adding to the header "Authorization" with value "Bearer API_KEY_ABOVE_AS_WELL"
so it looks like

"Authorization" "Bearer SG.asasfhiouce-JKIjjkvcdb_iouywerejkhwrnd"