# SendGrid Tutorial resulting in Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5, sendgrid

I apologize if this is a dupe question, but I have not found any solid information about this issue either on this site or on others.

With that being said, I am working on an MVC 5 web application. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) over on ASP.net.

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    await configSendGridasync(message);
}

private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
    myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                        "info@ycc.com", "Your Contractor Connection");
    myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
    myMessage.Text = message.Body;
    myMessage.Html = message.Body;

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
         Properties.Resources.SendGridUser,
         Properties.Resources.SendGridPassword,
         Properties.Resources.SendGridURL // necessary?
         );

    // Create a Web transport for sending email.
    var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

    // Send the email.
    if (transportWeb != null)
    {
        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Each time it gets to the `await transportWeb.SendAsync(myMessage)` line in the above method, this error shows up in the browser:

---

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *Bad Request*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Exception: Bad Request

```
Line 54:             if (transportWeb != null)
Line 55:             {
Line 56:                 await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
Line 57:             }
Line 58:             else
Line 59:             {
Line 60:                 Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
Line 61:                 await Task.FromResult(0);
Line 62:             }
```

---

I signed up for a free account over at https://sendgrid.com/, using the "Free Package Google", giving me 25,000 monthly credits. The account has been provisioned.

I have tried a bunch of things so far including: disabling SSL, putting username/password directly in the code instead of pulling them from the `Resources.resx` file, specifying the SMTP server inside the `NetworkCredential` object, and also tried changing `DeliverAsync(...)` to `Deliver()`.

I tried explicitly setting the `subject` instead of using `message.Subject`, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892185/bad-request-error-using-sendgrid-smtp-email-submission) suggested. I also tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` on the `callbackUrl` generated in the `Account/Register` method as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212263/getting-bad-request-in-rick-andersons-code-for-password-recovery). Same results, unfortunately.

Does anyone happen to have some insight as to what might be causing this to not function correctly?

Comment: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: @DJKRAZE I used NuGet from within VS2013 Community Edition to get the latest SendGrid. Is the one you linked different from the package I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using the built-in `SmtpClient` to get this working. Here is the code that I am using:

```
private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient(Properties.Resources.SendGridURL,587);

    var creds = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Resources.SendGridUser, Properties.Resources.SendGridPassword);

    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = creds;
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;

    var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);
    var from = new MailAddress("info@ycc.com", "Your Contractor Connection");

    var msg = new MailMessage();

    msg.To.Add(to);
    msg.From = from;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Subject = message.Subject;
    msg.Body = message.Body;

    await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

Even though it doesn't use SendGrid's C# API, the messages still show up on my SendGrid dashboard.

Comment: var creds = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Resources.SendGridUser, Properties.Resources.SendGridPassword); Here Properties.Resources.SendGridUser and Properties.Resources.SendGridPassword are not found

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel those are embedded in the program's resources file. They are string values. I did try putting them in hard-coded before posting this and subsequently finding a solution, which I Then posted.

Comment: I followed exactly what is described here but I am getting : "The server committed a protocol violation" ... Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @a.boussema makes sure you are using your sendgrid username NOT an email address. Server should be smtp.sendgrid.net. Play with your ports too; I believe there were three or four I tried before I finally got it working.

Comment: @Anders : Thanks a lot. My problem was non-payment of a bill :)) the error message was very confusing and I had to pass some multiple hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

It might be a problem with your credentials.

If you signed up with SendGrid through Windows Azure, then you need to do the following:

1. Log in to your `Azure Portal`
2. Navigate to the `Marketplace`
3. Locate and click on the `SendGrid` application
4. Down at the bottom, click on `Connection Info`
5. Use the `Username` and `Password` listed.

I was initially under the impression that I was to use my Azure account password until I found this.  Hope this corrects your problem like it did for me.

Comment: Also, note that in that tutorial the "mailAccount" setting should be set to your sendgrid username, NOT the email address of the account.

Comment: The username is generated and not the name supplied when you create the sendgrid resource.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using the correct "username" as the "mailAccount" setting.

This should be your sendgrid username, **NOT** the email address of the account you are trying to send from.

Answer (score 2):

I had created an SendGrid account via Azure,
I fixed this by setting these values in my Web.Config file:

```
<add key="mailAccount" value="azure_************@azure.com" />
<add key="mailPassword" value="[My Azure Password]" />
```

to my azure username and password. the username I found from the Azure Dashboard, I navigated to SendGrid Accounts >> [Clicked the Resource I had Created] >> Configurations. The password was the same one I set up the Azure account with.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue. solved by adding textcontent and htmlcontent. Before i was sending empty string.now its working
code below

```
var client = new SendGridClient(_apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress(_fromEmailAddress, _fromName);
            var to = new EmailAddress("devanathan.s@somedomain.com", "dev");
            var textcontent = "This is to test the mail functionality";
            var htmlcontent = "<div>Devanathan Testing mail</div>";
            var subject = "testing by sending mail";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, textcontent, htmlcontent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. All I had to do was to copy the appsettings in webconfig(see below) and paste it into the OTHER webconfig file (there are 2 of them in asp.net project).

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="mailAccount" value="xxUsernamexx" />
<add key="mailPassword" value="Password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was that I had the same email on TO and BCC field. Hope it helps others..

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, happened to have misspelled the name of the config value for the mailAccount (put mainAccount instead of the mailAccount).

```
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]);
        Web transportWeb = new Web(credential);
```

The config value was coming back as null but the exception wasnt raised and the empty username was assigned instead. Basically, put the breakpoint on the line "Web transportWeb = new Web(credential);" and see what username/password you are actually passing in credential, and see also the nevada_scout's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The company domain you have registered in SendGrid should be used to call the MailAddress API. Thus, if your company web site you are registering in SendGrid is `www.###.com` you should use:

```
var from = MailAddress("info@###.com", "Your Contractor Connection")
```